# Printing Parameter Values returning Unexpected Result, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces

I have the following python script snidbit:

```
inLines = sys.argv[0]

arcpy.AddMessage(inLines)
```

The input parameter is a multivalue input whereby the user can navigate to a file locations and choose multiple files as the input.

When I print out the variable, I get the follwoing:

> Y:\2012_data\INFRASTRUCTURE.gdb\Buildings;'Z:\DATA FOR
>   2009\Base.gdb\CREEKS_UTM';'Z:\DATA FOR 2009\Base.gdb\LAKES_UTM'

Notice on the Z:drive, it is returning the path with single quotes around it, whereas the Y:drive does not. I believe this is caused by the spaces in the Z:drive paths. Is there a way to force the Z:drive paths to return without the quotes?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. Python handles the parameters differently because of the path names. In the first parameter, there are no spaces in the file path. In the other 2 parameters, there are spaces. Python doesn't like spaces, so it forces the file path into a string value. I just wrote some code to override this.